# Custom 1-button player with HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, html5-audio

Working with the `<audio>` tag in some web development I've been doing lately, and one thing I'm trying to do is use it to build a word list and provide a pronunciation sample next to each word on the list.  Setting this up isn't hard at all, however this sort of application hardly requires the full set of controls; just a play button.

The `controls` element of the `<audio>` tag doesn't seem to be that well documented at all, however; all I can find on it is "always put 'on' here, unless you want to build your own player".  I don't want to build my own player, however, I just want a simple, 1-button play interface with nothing else, ideally without requiring JavaScript or Flash.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's fairly simple. You just need to call the play method on the `audio` DOM object when something is clicked. The something could be an image, text, link, or whatever suits.

Here's one possible way:

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src=".."></audio></a>
```

[See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4bxrR/750/)

Comment: The code sample is great. But the audio sample in your jsfiddle is not exactly pleasant! :)