# How can I change play/button images in HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, controls

I have the code of audio player. How can I change the picture of play/pause button when press?

```
<div class="onlineradio"><img src="images/Radio.jpg" alt="" />
<p><video id="yourAudio" width="0" height="0">
    <source src='http://178.219.160.126:8000/stream.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' preload="auto" />
</video> <a id="audioControl" href="#"><img src="images/radioscalebutton.png" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Everything is fine, you just need to change the URL of the image, e.g. `images/radioscalebutton.png`.

Comment: refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472459/custom-1-button-player-with-html5-audio-tag

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a final working solution with custom audio controls (play and pause) with toggling state button. If something is not clear for you, please ask.

Here is the working solution and [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnaad46d/2/):

```js
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl'),
    playButton = document.getElementById('play'),
    pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function toggleButton() {
    if (playButton.style.display === 'none') {
        playButton.style.display = 'block';
        pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        playButton.style.display = 'none';
        pauseButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

ctrl.onclick = function () {

    if (yourAudio.paused) {
        yourAudio.play();
    } else {
        yourAudio.pause();
    }
    
    toggleButton();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

```css
#audioControl img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#pause {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="onlineradio">
    <img src="images/Radio.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>
        <audio id="yourAudio">
            <source src='http://178.219.160.126:8000/stream.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' preload="auto" />
        </audio>
        <a id="audioControl" href="#">
            <img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-3d-buttons-icons-media/002110-glossy-black-3d-button-icon-media-a-media22-arrow-forward1.png" id="play"/>
            <img src="https://www.wisc-online.com/asset-repository/getfile?id=415&getType=view" id="pause"/>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can download the images of controls and use refer to them locally.